# Cache ajax response for loading records - Rails 3

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

I have the following code which retrieves the current users notifications and renders a partial each time the `#notifications` link is clicked via ajax. .

How can I cache the ajax response so that, after the first time a user clicks the `#notifications` button, whilst remaining on the same page, the results are loaded from the cache rather than re-retrieving them every time the link is clicked?

notifications.js.coffee

```
jQuery ->
  $("#notifications").click ->
      $.ajax
        url: "/activities/notifications"
        dataType: "html"
        type: "GET"
        success: (html) ->
          $("#notifications-area").html html
```

i have tried adding $.ajaxSetup({"cache" : true }) however this loaded the records twice and then cached the response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I went a slightly simpler route. When #notifications is clicked, I push an object into an array. If the length of the array is less then or equal to 1 then i'll go a head and retrieve the notifications via .get() and vice versa.

```
jQuery ->
  arr = []
  $("#notifications").click ->
    arr.push(1)
    if arr.length <= 1
     $.get("/activities/notifications", (data) ->
           $("#notifications-area").html data )
```

Comment: our own answer does not store the data as you demanded but only remembers that the ajax call has been made (actually how often, but that is not helpful) See my answer for how to actually store the response data.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it with `localStorage`  in html5

```
Notifications = (->
  init = ->
   get: (user_id) ->
      html = localStorage.getItem(user_id)
      if html
        $("#notifications-area").html html
        true
      else
        false
    set: (user_id) ->
      $.ajax
        url: "/activities/notifications"
        dataType: "html"
        type: "GET"
        success: (html) ->
          localStorage.setItem user_id, html
          $("#notifications-area").html html

  instantiated = undefined
  getInstance: ->
    instantiated = init()  unless instantiated
    instantiated
)()
$("#notifications").click ->
  Notifications.getInstance().set user_id  unless Notifications.getInstance().get(user_id)
```

Current browsers supports `localStorage`

- IE 8.0+
- Firefox 3.5+
- Safari 4.0+
- Chrome 4.0+
- Opera 10.5+
- iPhone 2.0+
- Android 2.0+

Comment: Hi Hawk, thanks for this, local storage indeed seems like a likely solution. Straight out of the box it doesn't seem to work as it doesn't fetch the records upon clicking the link, unfortunately my js isn't proficient enough to know where its going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You can store the response of the ajax call by attaching it to the link using jquerys data() method like so:

```
$ ->
  $("#notifications").click ->
    node = $(this)  
    if data = node.data('response')
      $("#notifications-area").html data
    else
      $.get("/activities/notifications", (data) ->
        node.data 'response', data     # this stores the response data for later
        $("#notifications-area").html data
```